# Laravel 4 ViewModel (with Mustache)

Tags: php, mvvm, laravel, laravel-4, viewmodel

I am looking to extend Laravel 4 to include `ViewModel` objects, or perhaps make `Views` act like a `ViewModel` and create a separate templates section. I'd prefer to use Mustache for this, but it isn't necessary.

Are there any good libraries or code snippets that would allow me to extend the basic Laravel functionality and insert a `ViewModel` between my controllers and the HTML templates. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question - are [ViewComposers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) not suitable?

Depending what you are trying to achieve you can also hook into the View Composer event that gets fired before a view is composed, something like this:

*app/start/global.php or in PackageServiceProvider*

```
\Event::listen('composing: *', function($view) {
     //custom code here acting upon the instantiated View object
}
```

where I have entered `composing: *`, * corresponds to the view name, in this case matching any view name.

You can take this a step further by namespacing your views and creating Event listeners that respond to different namespaces You could register a new namespace for your mustache views and then respond just to views in that namespace, often I will put my mustache view in the public dir so they can be accessed client side so you may do something like this:

*app/start/global.php or in PackageServiceProvider*

```
\View::addNamespace('m', public_path() . '/views');
\Event::listen('composing: m::*', function($view) {
     //custom code here acting upon the instantiated View object when a namespaced mustache view is composed.
}
```

You would then make those views with:

```
View:make('m::view_name')
```

to make the view

> public/views/view_name.mustache

If the above don't meet you needs you could take a look at [Presenter](https://github.com/robclancy/presenter) - I havent tried this package but might be what your looking for.

Hope this helps, sorry if I've misunderstood your question

Comment: That gets close, but what I am looking for is a class I can pass data into that can have functions to massage the data before it is passed to the template. The `ViewComposers` look compelling, but aren't broken out per view/template. I want one `ViewModel` per template rendered.

Comment: I have edited my answer - see the presenter package at the bottom, this may be what youre looking for. I havent used it though as I've found a combination of get and set attribute methods within models with the above techniques have been sufficient to do what I've needed.